# How should we interpret COVID-19 vaccines "efficacy"?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

Different COVID-19 vaccines are said to have x% efficacy (x ~ 85%-95%). How should we understand this? There are several ways in which we could interpret this measure:

Is it the expected percentage of people who develop antibodies? The percentage of people who do not develop any symptoms after being exposed to COVID-19?

Comment: A good place to start would be the manufacturers of the vaccines and the regulatory agencies that have approved them. What have you found there?

Comment: Dupe at biology: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/96941/27148 I think there is a duplicate here but I forget which. In summary, all the major trials I am aware of defined efficacy as a ratio of the number of vaccinated to unvaccinated people who get ill.

Comment: @BryanKrause iirc, efficacy in trials was measured using criteria like death, hospitalization, serious illness, mild illness, etc.

Comment: @Armand Those were alternative endpoints. The primary endpoints were symptomatic illness, that's it.